# 'Catch branch is identical' however still requires me to catch it

Tags: java, try-catch

Whilst reading through my code I noticed my IDE was listing a warning with the following message:

> Reports identical catch sections in try blocks under JDK 7. A quickfix is available to collapse the sections into a multi-catch section.

And also specifies that this warning is thrown for JDK 7+

The try block is as follows:

```
try {
    FileInputStream e = new FileInputStream("outings.ser");
    ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(e);
    return (ArrayList)inputStream.readObject();
} catch (FileNotFoundException var3) {
    var3.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException var5) {
    var5.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

However when removing (the catch blocks that threw that particular warning):

```
catch (ClassNotFoundException var5) {
    var5.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I would still get errors at:

```
ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(e);
return (ArrayList)inputStream.readObject();
```

---

Am I missing something obvious that I haven't figured out so far?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

So, since I'm seeing that same warning in IntelliJ (and I think you're using IntelliJ too), why not let <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> if you rather) show you what it means?

You can collapse exception branches if they're identical, and with the multi-catch syntax, you'll wind up with one catch statement that does the same thing as your three:

```
try {
    FileInputStream e = new FileInputStream("outings.ser");
    ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(e);
    return (ArrayList)inputStream.readObject();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException var3) {
    var3.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

Comment: It's important to note that types in a multi-catch must be disjoint. +1 for the proper use of a multi-catch statement.

Comment: disjoint means that classes are not sub/superclasses of each other.

Comment: The hint to "collapse" actually solved the issue with my warning. Thanks!